# AJAX Success/error messages not functioning on Chrome for iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, google-chrome

I have recently implemented a form that is processed via AJAX to an API. The form has two message divs with 'display: none' that show on either success or error states. The submit script works fine on chrome, firefox and Safari for desktop. However, on Chrome for iOS, both of the messages are displayed (without correct styling) without interacting with the form at all.

Why is this? I can't seem to work out if this is a styling or AJAX/Javascript incompatibility in Chrome for iOS. I would appreciate it if anyone at all could help me out here. I have attached an example of the issue.

[image: Success and error messages displaying together, untriggered]

```js
$('.contactForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('.contactForm')[0].checkValidity()) {
        var URL = '';
        var data = {
            firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
            lastName: $('#lastName').val(),
            contactNumber: $('#contactNumber').val(),
            emailAddress: $('#emailAddress').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: URL,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function () {
                $('.success-message').show();
                $('#firstName').val('');
                $('#lastName').val('');
                $('#contactNumber').val('');
                $('#emailAddress').val('');
            },
            error: function () {
                $('.error-message').show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.contact-form {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.success-message {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #81b26b;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #7aa864;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.success-message p,
.error-message p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.error-message {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ef2917;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #b02e0c;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.contactForm {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contact-us form input {
    width: 80%;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #aeaeae;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: .5s
}

.contact-us form input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border: 2px solid #f06530
}

.contact-us form input::placeholder {
    opacity: 0
}

.contact-us form .wire-cta {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #f06530
}

.contact-us button {
    margin: 0 5px 10px 0
}

.submit {
    background-color: #f06530;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="contactForm">
                        <div class="user-messages">
                          <div class="success-message">
                            <p>
                                Thanks for your interest, we look forward to speaking with you soon!
                            </p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="error-message">
                            <p>
                                There seems to be an issue, please re-submit the form or contact us direct.
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
                        <label for="contactName">Contact Number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" name="contactNumber" id="contactNumber" placeholder="Contact Number" pattern="^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$" required/>
                        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn click submit">Get in touch</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn wire-cta">Clear</button>
                      </form>
```